# How to install a wordpress website template on an existing website?

Tags: templates, page-template

I just downloaded a template called Senna for my website. It's a responsive wordpress template, and I don't have knowledge of how to use wordpress templates.

My currently website is html based on [117.boxhost.me](http://117.boxhost.me) ... The website has auto install feature of installing wordpress to folder(s)... I installed wordpress to a subdirectory: [/wordpress](http://117.boxhost.me/wordpress/).

Currently I've kept the main site in html, and I post blog posts on the wordpress. I need to combine the main site with the wordpress and don't want to disturb the directory /wordpress. That's because I've already posted the blog links elsewhere on the internet and so anyone trying to read the articles won't be able to find the pages if I move the blogs from subfolder to main folder.

I'm trying to keep the index.html of root website as a redirect page with `"meta=refresh"` tag. So the main site would then be at : `117.boxhost.me/wordpress/` 
But I don't know how to change the current set of pages to a webpage form.

What I know about wordpress templates is: Install wordpress > Upload the images and content of the pages > And then upload the zip file as a theme for the wordpress.

After that I don't know if it's easy to create the pages in the new theme/template or would that disturb or damage the blogs posts or their permanent-url...

Also, the downloaded file doesn't contain any zip files, only a 5 folders including a folder Senna, with subfolders (templates, etc)

That's mostly all I need to ask.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a user-support question that would be better asked on the [WordPress.org support forums](http://wordpress.org/support). The Codex entries for [Integrating WordPress into your Website](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website) and [Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) may also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @ChipBennett , I'll ask the question on the forum instead then. I thought I could ask it here, cause I still don't understand what you mean by "user-support" question. Are only wordpress-plugin related questions asked here?

Comment: Core and Theme-development questions are certainly welcome. If you have specific questions as you step into/through developing a Theme, feel free to ask!